# A graph with loops and multiple edges with the given degrees of vertices is (2,2,4,6,6)

Tags: graph-theory

I was solving some question About loops and multiple edges graphs

Does there exists a loop and multiple edges graph With 5 vertices and degrees 2,2,4,6,6

I tried to sketch such type of graph but i couldn't..thank you..

Comment: Can you provide more information about the graph (whether it is simple or not)?

Comment: Loops and multiple edges seems to be explicitely meaning not "simple graph".

Answer (score 1):

Since each degree is even, you can simply take a 5 isolated vertices and have them contain $1,1,2,3$ and $3$ loops each.